# Unable to activate app as device admin on android oreo(API level 26)

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, device-admin

When I try to activate my app as device admin an click **Activate this device admin app**, I am sent back to the previous screen and the device admin is not activated.

Receiver in manifes:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permissions.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_policies" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver class:

```
public class MyDeviceAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver
{
    public void onEnabled(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("DeviceAdmin", "OnEnabled");
        super.onEnabled(context, intent);
        SharedPreferences.Editor defaultPrefEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        defaultPrefEditor.putBoolean(context.getString(R.string.pref_device_admin_status), true);
        defaultPrefEditor.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("DeviceAdmin", "OnDisabled");
        super.onDisabled(context, intent);
        SharedPreferences.Editor defaultPrefEditor =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        defaultPrefEditor.putBoolean(context.getString(R.string.pref_device_admin_status), false);
        defaultPrefEditor.apply();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
android:permission="android.permissions.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
```

I wrote `permissions` when it should be `permission`.